# Winrm not able to use dnscmd - Windows server 2012 R2 Standard server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

I am trying to manage a Windows server 2012 R2 Standard server over winrm.  On the server I would like to run dnscmd from the rsat package. You can see below if I just run the dnscmd  in the power shell prompt it is successful. However when I invoke it remotely over winrm the command fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

```bsh
PS C:\Windows\system32> dnscmd adServer /RecordDelete mycompany.com newTestRecord A /f
Deleted A record(s) at mycompany.com 
Command completed successfully.


PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-WsMan localhost
wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0


PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {
>> dnscmd adServer /RecordDelete mycompany.com newTestRecord A /f
>> } 
Command failed:  ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED     5    0x5


PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {
>> hostname
>> }
myServerHostname
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was double-hop/multi-hop. When you login over winRM it doesn't want to allow you to use the same credential token to reach to a different machine. I got around this issue by connecting over winrm then opening up a nested Powershell session. It's essentially refreshes the tokens allowing the user to connect to the active directory server.

Please see the following for more information

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sergey_babkins_blog/2015/03/18/another-solution-to-multi-hop-powershell-remoting/

Make sure to install Remote Server Administration Tools  (RSAT) for dnscmd.

```
$password = '{pass}' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$username = '{user}'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName svc_dns_middleMan -ScriptBlock {
  '{dnscmd_commands}'
}
```